# How to see results of console.profile()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

According to [Chrome Console API Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#profile) and [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/profile), using `console.profile('label')` to start profiling and later using `console.endProfile()` to end profiling, should result in a profile added to Profiles (has been since renamed to Performance) panel in Chrome.

This works for me in Firefox, but I don't get any profiles when I run my code in Chrome. Instead I get the warning:

> DevTools: CPU profile parser is fixing 16 missing samples.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug in Chrome DevTools?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104710/chrome-cpu-profile-parser-is-fixing-n-missing-samples

Answer (score 50):

Turns out the profile goes into a different panel:

> CPU profiles added to the JavaScript profiler panel. You can open it by clicking three dots menu (in the top right corner)
>    ⋮-> More tools -> JavaScript Profiler.

Answer (score 6):

The profiling can be observed from below code part.

```js
function profileTest(callback) {      
  let i = 0;
  let work = setInterval(function() {         
      if(i == 3) {
         callback();
         clearInterval(work);        
         return;     
      }
      console.log('Doing some work..');
      i = i + 1;
  }, 1000);     
}

console.profile("profileTest()");
profileTest(function(){
  console.profileEnd();
});
```

Note: setInterval is used for simulation purpose.

As @atavakoli have already answered, created profile can be seen in 'CPU PROFILES' part in 'Javascript Profiler' tab that can be opened from Developer Tools → Three dots → More tools. For example below screenshot shows the result profile of above code part.

[image: How to open Javascript Profiler]

See following link: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/devtools-javascript-cpu-profile-migration

For the warning message, below question link can be referred.

[Chrome: CPU profile parser is fixing n missing samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104710/chrome-cpu-profile-parser-is-fixing-n-missing-samples)